# I want to minimize the runtime of this Python program

Tags: python-3.x

Code that I want to minimize the runtime, it goes through an array of number and finds the max between the current max_product and the next product.

```
def max_pairwise_product(numbers):
    n = len(numbers)
    max_product = 0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            max_product = max(max_product,numbers[i]*numbers[j])
            return max_product

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_n = int(input())
    input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(max_pairwise_product(input_numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to find the maximum product of any two non-identical elements of a numeric array. You are currently doing that by calculating each product. This algorithm has *n²/2* calculations and comparisons, while all you actually need to do is much less:

We know from basic math that the two largest numbers in the original array will have the largest product. So all you need to do is:

- Find the two largest integers in the array
- multiply them.

You could do so by sorting the original array or just skimming through the array to find the two largest elements (which is a bit more tricky as it sounds because those two elements could have the *same value* but may not be the *same element*)

As a side note: In the future, please format your posts so that a reader may actually understand what your code does without going through hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the numbers and multiplying the last two elements would give better time complexity than O(n^2).

Sort - O(nlogn) 
Multiplication -  O(1)

```
def max_pairwise_product(numbers):
    n = len(numbers)
    max_product = 0
    numbers.sort()
    if ((numbers[n-1] >0) and (numbers[n-2] >0)):
        max_product = numbers[n-1]*numbers[n-2]
    return max_product

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_n = int(input())
    input_numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    print(max_pairwise_product(input_numbers))
```